# Using drawRect, setNeedsDisplay and layoutSubViews

Tags: iphone

Is there any ground rule for using methods like drawRect, setNeedsDisplay and layoutSubViews?
I believe they adversely affect the app performance. Is there any preferred alternatives for these messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this isn't an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716351/quartz-2d-drawrect-method-iphone), I believe [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716351/quartz-2d-drawrect-method-iphone/717237#717237) still applies.

In summary, `-drawRect:` will redraw the content within a view, which is an expensive operation.  Avoid redrawing if you can by layering content and moving or hiding those layers as needed.

However, these redraws typically will only have a significant performance impact if there are many of them done in rapid succession, like when trying to animate content.  One-off redraws of static UI elements will not perceptively slow things down.