# How to disable the blue color highlight in tab bar in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am customizing the tab bar in iOS, how to disable the blue color glow at the highlighted tab bar item ?

Will apple reject the app which disables the default blue color glow at the selected item ?

Thanks.

Comment: What my post was down voted ? Any reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre IOS5, you can only do this with a "hack" to over-ride drawrect.

I would recommend against it, even though I have done it and had an app accepted with it (that was over a year ago though).

In IOS5 this will likely be possible with the new customisation api's.

Comment: Why do you against the customization of tab bar ?

Comment: An Apple engineer recommended I avoided doing this when I asked them about it at a tech-talk. In some Apple videos from ADC they also recommend against it.  Over-riding drawRect in my experience is problematic and can cause unexpected results in some circumstances leading to the requirement of non-neat coding / other hacks to compensate. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716351/quartz-2d-drawrect-method-iphone/717237#717237